# Pick random points in an earth circle

Tags: python, google-maps

All I need is the ability to create random points within a radius of another point.

so given `self.fence.latitude` and `self.fence.longitude` and `self.fence.radius` I should be able to generate random points with the following code (i'm writing in python/django and using numpy but all these calcs can be done using the standard math library)

for whatever reason my points are showing up in a line. I need random points.

```
# angle for this random point
angle = numpy.float128(2 * numpy.pi * numpy.random.random_sample())
# radius from fence center
radius = numpy.float128(self.fence.radius) * numpy.random.random_sample()

# diff from ceneter in radians
latitudinal_diff_rad = radius * numpy.sin(angle) / numpy.float128(settings.EARTH_RADIUS)
longitudinal_diff_rad = radius * numpy.cos(angle) / numpy.float128(settings.EARTH_RADIUS)

# radians to degrees
latitudinal_diff = latitudinal_diff_rad * 180 / numpy.pi
longitudinal_diff = longitudinal_diff_rad * 180 / numpy.pi

try :
     # create the item
    item = Item(
        latitude = numpy.float128(self.fence.latitude) + latitudinal_diff,
        longitude = numpy.float128(self.fence.longitude) + latitudinal_diff,
    )
    item.save()

except IntegrityError, e :
    continue
    print e
```

[image: stupid line]

What am i doing wrong?

#### Edit

```
# this was the math I was using before I simplified it and switched to numpy lib
distance_from_point = float(self.fence.radius) * random.random()
unit_length = distance_from_point / settings.EARTH_RADIUS
longitudinal_diff_rad = ((unit_length) * (2 * random.random() - 1))
latitudinal_diff_rad = math.acos(math.cos(unit_length) / math.cos(longitudinal_diff_rad))
```

Comment: I see three errors right off: (1) you won't get a circle with this approach due to the metric distortions in using latitude and longitude; (2) you appear to confound meters with degrees in the calculation of the radius; and (3) there are some (obvious) typos in the last calculations.  Your code could be *approximately* fixed if you know you will be making small circles (a few tens of kilometers or less) at points far from the poles.  Would that be the case?

Comment: lets start back at the beginning of the problem. I am trying to find random points within a certain radius of another point. The distribution doesn't have to be perfectly random, the fence radius will be between 10 to 200km roughly. I wasn't feeling great about my math when I tossed this up here, how would you fix it?

Comment: Do you have the ability to project your data, such as a general projection library?  Re the edit, if you want to generate points within a *disk* uniformly at random (rather than just along its circular boundary), then you need to make the distance equal to the *square root* of a uniform value: that's because there isn't too much area close to the center; most of the circle's area is near its perimeter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found my error...

```
longitude = numpy.float128(self.fence.longitude) + latitudinal_diff,
```

should be

```
longitude = numpy.float128(self.fence.longitude) + longitudinal_diff,
```

explains my 45 degree angle.

Comment: Great. Please mark this as the accepted answer when you can (may have to wait a day). That way future readers will know what worked to fix the issue.

Comment: yea i do have to wait a day to accept it. I'm not sure how helpful this will be for future folks as it was just a copy paste error.

Comment: If anything it serves as a reminder to check closely for copy/paste (and syntax) errors. There are many similar examples in the questions on this site.